# Update the choices argument of the same radioButtons in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to update the choices-argument from a radioButtons-widget in R/shiny. When a user selected a choice, the choices argument should be updated based on the first choice of the user. I mocked this with 4 random letters with the sample-function. It appears that the update does not stop and is updated several times. How do I prevent the behavior of updating multiple times?

Here is code to reproduce my approach:

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
    radioButtons("answerchoice", label = "item", choices = sample(letters, 4), selected = NULL,
                 )
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$answerchoice,{
        updateRadioButtons(
            session = session,
            inputId = "answerchoice",
            choices = sample(letters, 4)
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the default setting of `selected = NULL` might be the problem. `radioButton` is picking one value initally. This may cause the multiple updates. By setting `selected` to nothing. The app is not updating uncontrollably.

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("answerchoice",
               label = "item", 
               choices = sample(letters, 4),
               selected =  character(0)
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$answerchoice,{
    updateRadioButtons(
      session = session,
      inputId = "answerchoice",
      choices = sample(letters, 4),
      selected =  character(0)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```